# Skip values in PHP XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using `PHP` `xpath` to read values from `XML`. I have condition like below where I want to get Id of **"a"** where there is only name tag in **"b"**. and skip if any other tag is present along with name. expected out put is 1. but I am getting all the Ids of **"a"** tag. I am using `Xpath` as

```
$xml->xpath("//a[b/name = 'value1' ]/@id");
```

how I can skip ids 2 and 3 and get output 1

sample XML

```
<a id="1">
    <b>
        <name> value1 </name>
    </b>
</a>
<a id="2">
    <b>
        <name> value1 </name>
        <other> value2 </other>
    </b>
</a>
<a id="3">
    <b>
        <name> value1 </name>
        <other> value3 </other>
    </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`//a/b[count(*) = 1 and count(name) = 1]/../@id`